# convert simple json array to plain text

Tags: json, bash, zsh, jq

The current command I am using is:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.full+json" -H "Authorization: 7c258a9869f33c1e1e1f74fbb32f07c86cb5a75b" "https://api.github.com/repos/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/git/trees/master?recursive=1" | jq '.tree[]|.path'
```

I have a return value like

```
[
  ".editorconfig",
  ".gitattributes",
  ".gitignore",
  ".revision-hash",
  ".travis.yml",
  ".version",
  "COPYING.md",
  "HACKING.md",
  "INSTALL.md",
  "Makefile",
  "README.md",
  "changelog.md",
  "docs",
  "docs/highlighters.md",
  "docs/highlighters",
  "docs/highlighters/brackets.md",
  "docs/highlighters/cursor.md",
  "docs/highlighters/line.md",
  .....
]
```

I want the return value to be like

```
.editorconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.revision-hash
.travis.yml
.version
COPYING.md
HACKING.md
INSTALL.md
Makefile
README.md
changelog.md
docs
docs/highlighters.md
docs/highlighters
docs/highlighters/brackets.md
docs/highlighters/cursor.md
docs/highlighters/line.md
....
```

Comment: Is that a **private** auth key?

Comment: No, I changed the auth key. It is from github api documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s `-r` option ([docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)):

```
jq -r '.tree[]|.path' < <(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.full+json" -H "Authorization: <MY-KEY>" "https://api.github.com/repos/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/git/trees/master?recursive=1")
```

This uses a bash [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) so the interesting part of the answer shows up first. You could write `curl ... | jq ...`

Result:

```
editorconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.revision-hash
.travis.yml
.version
COPYING.md
HACKING.md
...
```